# Visualizing parametric equations without Desmos/Mathematica

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, curves, parametric

How can I visualize and have a feel for parametric curves and regions? I'm taking multivariable calculus and it's been pretty hard for me to visualize parametric equations in $\mathbb{R}^2$, let alone $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Let's take these examples: $\log(xy)\leq 0$, $|x+y|\leq 1$

What am I generally supposed to do in order to visualize parametric curves and regions? Is there a standard method to test and try the function?

Comment: On a second note: what does it mean when we "parameterize" a function?

Comment: The inequalities you list here don't describe *curves*, rather they are *regions*, i.e. subsets of $\mathbb R^2$. For instance, if $x>0$,$$\log(xy)\le0\implies\log(y)\le\log\left(\frac1x\right)\implies y\le\frac1x$$which is the region bounded by the hyperbola $y=\frac1x$ and the coordinates axes in the first quadrants of the $(x,y)$ plane.

Comment: Why do you want to do it without Desmos/Mathematica? (Just curious).

Comment: @VictorQuezada It's an exercise from my textbook to plot it. I assume that I should be plotting them without any help from external software

Comment: OK. Sometimes, I've tried to do the same by means of paperboard, fixing the origin of the graphs and bending the planes accordingly to every function. But before that, I visualize the functions by means of software for giving me an idea of how I must treat them.